# Economics of forgetting

Tags: game-theory, reference-request, uncertainty

I'm interested to know economic justifications of forgetting in various fields.

On example is [Green and Porter(1984)](http://www.nuff.ox.ac.uk/users/klemperer/IO_Files/nooncooperative%20collussion%20green%20and%20porter.pdf). To sustain a Cartel, Cartel members have incentive to forget deviations in a sufficiently distant past.

Another is [Ekmekciy(2011)](https://www.sabanciuniv.edu/HaberlerDuyurular/Documents/DD20061109143555/MehmetEkmekci.pdf) which shows that a rating system works better if it stops publicize misconducts, once they're old enough.

Literature on a more abstract level is also welcomed, e.g. results like it's more socially desirable in a dynamic games, some agents are restricted to stationary strategies.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not what you are looking for, but a related concept is regret. Orphanides and Zervos (1995) is a classic paper on rational regret in a health economics concept http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2138580?uid=3739840&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21106216442271

There's also plenty of irrational regret papers, mostly just boiling down to hyperbolic discounting models.

Comment: Regret aversion seems somewhat orthogonal to agents which "forget". Forgetfulness seems to be much better modeled by imperfect recall in games.

Answer (score 4):

This topic has been studied widely in the theory of repeated games. See for example:

Robert J. Aumann, Sylvain Sorin: [Cooperation and bounded recall](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0899825689900031), Games and Economic Behavior, Vol. 1, No. 1. (March 1989)